# Database vs DataMart vs Data Warehouse vs Data Lake

Tags: database, comparison, data-warehouse, data-lake, datamart

Looking for the high-level differences/comparison among

- Database
- Data Mart (Top-down approach)
- Data Warehouse
- Data Lake
- Data Lakehouse

Please use relative comparison when specifics are not available.

Comment: Would it be practical to update this question to also consider the Data Lakehouse?

Comment: @ShawnEary - Good one! I updated the question and the answer as well!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Included below is a high-level comparison between the various data tiers mentioned. Please feel free to drop a comment if any of these need corrections.

| Feature | Database | Data Mart | Data Warehouse | Data Lake | Data Lakehouse |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Source | Single | Single | Multiple | Multiple | Multiple |
| Structure | Structured | Structured | Structured | Raw | Structured, semi-structured, and unstructured |
| Purpose | Determined | Determined | Determined | Determined | Determined |
| Storage | Centralized | Decentralized | Centralized | Centralized | Centralized |
| Data Format | Detailed | Summarized | Both detailed and summarized | All | All |
| Flexibility | Low | Medium | Medium | High | High |
| Primary Use | Transactional | Reporting | Analytics & Reporting | Analytics | Analytics |
| Cost | Low | Medium | Medium | High | High |
| Data Volume | Low | Low | Medium | High | High |
| Development | Top-down | Bottom-up | Top-down | All | All |
| Design Time | Medium | Medium | High | Low | Low |
| Volatility | Medium | Low | None | None | None |
| Data Operations | CRUD | CR | CRU | CR | CRUD |
| Subject Area | Single | Single | Multiple | Multiple | Multiple |
| Design Schema | Relational | Multi-dimensional | Relational | No schema | Hybrid |

**Notes:**

- The cost of a data lakehouse can be lower than a data warehouse if the data is stored in a cloud-based object storage system.
- The data volume of a data lake can be much higher than a data warehouse or data mart.
- The development time for a data lakehouse can be lower than a data warehouse if the data is already stored in a cloud-based object storage system.
- The volatility of a data lake can be higher than a data warehouse or data mart because the data is not always structured and may change frequently.

**Fit-gap**

- If you need a low-cost, flexible repository for structured data, then a database is a good option.
- If you need a repository for summarized data for reporting purposes, then a data mart is a good option.
- If you need a repository for detailed data for analytics and reporting purposes, then a data warehouse is a good option.
- If you need a repository for all types of data for analytics and machine learning purposes, then a data lakehouse is a good option.

Comment: Nice answer. You know you can just type a [markdown table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) into your answer, rather than a code snippet with generation and screenshot of that?

Anyway, could you please clarify if "design time" is the design of the database, or design of things which use the database?

Comment: Thanks @falsePockets. Updated it to Markdown Table :). As for the design time - it's for the design of the datastore, it's infra, layout, clustering, replication, scaling, security, integration mechanisms, etc.